# Divide a 2D circular plane into tiles

Tags: 2d, space, projection, tile

I've been playing with making a 2D building game/platformer, and I've been wondering how I would go about making the world circular, or rather how I would project/draw the world in a way that makes it look like a planet but still handle the individual "tiles" as quadratic mathematical entities.

Comment: While I think this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, you might try using triangle or hexagon tiles instead of squares: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368527/geodesic-dome-of-hexagons

Comment: See [this blog](https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1640-hexagon-tiling-of-sphere/).